# How to real-time monitor the emails?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, gmail, quota

Good day!
I want to offer the implementation of google apps to my company.
Also we have a need to reply on messages, that we recieve through our web-site in 10 minutes time limit. For this purpose our big team of sales managers a handling emails when they have a free time. 
So i want to write the script (web application) that will indicate all the income emails with countdown. Every sales manager could click on email and reply on it from web interface.

I wrote the program, that every 5 sec. take all the emails from special label (all these emails are drops in this label-folder). And when smbdy replies on it - it moves to another label.

But after couple of hours i receive the message that i am above the quota.
As i see the daily qouta to read-write operations is 20 000k.

Is any ability to solve my problem?
Increas quota? or maybe there are any another possibilities to monitor emails in real-time.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gmail API recently added push notifications via the google cloud pub/sub service.  I wrote an example script on how to do this is Google Apps Script. You can view the code at:

https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-Gmail-Push-Notifications

Answer (score 0):

This is directly from the documentation:

Gmail REST API  [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota)

If you have [enabled billing](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#billing) for your project, you can see the quota percentage for each API. You can view and change quotas from the API section's API Library and Enabled APIs links. Selecting an API from the API Library list or from the Enabled APIs page takes you to a page with overview, usage, and quota links for that API. Choosing Quota lets you view and change quota-related settings. Choosing Usage provides you with usage statistics as well as response code and method information.